# Troubleshooting Google Sign-In: Image Not Loading on Subsequent Browser Opens (React.js)

Tags: reactjs, session, oauth, google-signin

I am using google sign in to get the profile name and image of an user.

```
import { useGoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';

const doLogin = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: async tokenResponse => {
        let credentialResponse = await (await
            fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' +               
                tokenResponse.access_token)
        ).json();
        login(credentialResponse);
        setState(1);
    },
});
```

I get the name and picture from the credentialResponse object and store it in localStorage.
The next time I open the browser the image doesn't load.
Why is that?
When I console log the img link and open it in a new tab, it does work.
And when I refresh my website after doing this, it loads in my website as well.

Is this actually the way of handling 'Keep signed in' ?

I couldn't find any tutorial on how to maintain sessions of google sign in.